# Match rows against elements in an array

Tags: php, mysql

I have a sql request to do with a php array to find all the occurrences of a search bar.

I can't get this done. This is my code :

```
    $texte = $_POST['texte'];
    $texte = explode(" ", $texte);
    $query_parts = array();

    //Proximité
    foreach ($texte as $value) {
        $value = "%".$value."%";
    }



    $sql = "SELECT * FROM PROXIMITE WHERE titrefr LIKE ':texte'";
    $req = $bd->requete_obj($sql, array('texte'=>$texte));

    while($select = $req->fetch()){
        error_log('Test');
    }
```

Comment: request_obj and not requete_obj

Comment: I'm french, this is a database class I made.

Comment: Since you're using placeholders you do not want to put in anything but the placeholder itself. That is remove the single quotes: `'`. Since you're using PDO, presumably, that will handle the quoting for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your foreach-loop does not actually modify the variables, because they are passed by Value - meaning a copy.
to modify them, you have to pass them by reference:

```
foreach ($texte as &$value) {
    $value = "%".$value."%";
}
```

that way, the actual values in your array are being manipulated.

secondly: you can not give your database an array as parameter. instead, you could loop through the array. if you implement that in your first loop, you don't even have to use references anymore:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM PROXIMITE WHERE titrefr LIKE :texte";
foreach ($texte as $value) {
    $value = "%".$value."%";
    $req = $bd->requete_obj($sql, array('texte'=>$value));
    while($select = $req->fetch()){
        error_log('Test');
    }
}
```

Comment: PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion

Comment: you're welcome - but you should think about restructuring your dataflows. running one query for every word is not exactly efficient.